# Problem about problem solving

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving

I am having some problems on how to solve problems. When I read a chapter on say group theory or real analysis, I feel that I have understood the concepts quite well, but when I start solving exercises, after 5 or 6 problems I get stuck. When I see a tough problem, I get messed and cannot find how to come out of it. When I see the solution I have no problem in understanding it. I think about many things but cannot come up with a solution. Is it a problem of my basics not being right? I have an entrance exam & being in this situation is frustrating for me. Please help.

Comment: Could it be that same of the problems are _meant_ to be really hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's *possible* that the books your reading have really bad exercises. But if this happens often, the more likely problem is that your feeling that you have grabbed the concepts quite well must be mistaken.

As useful test, when you look at a problem, is to ask yourself "Can I define precisely every single term used in this problem? " And then "What theorems do I know about these things?" If you can't recite the theorems -- with all the hypotheses! -- then you're probably not going to be able to do the problem. It's like trying to build a cabinet while you keep forgetting there's a saw in your toolbox.

I know that's not a lot of help, but it's the best I can do without more detail.

Comment: Can u help me which are the books I should read on real,complex analysis,metric spaces ,linear algebra please.Should I start fresh?What's your take@John

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you start at the beginning: get a copy of Michael Spivak's *Calculus* and do about half of the problems in it. You probably already *know* calculus, so you'll think this'll be easy...but it won't. Because Spivak's book is really a very rigorous introduction to analysis as well, and successfully doing those problems will get you on track for the next book. (It also happens to be beautifully written!)

Comment: Can you please help me out in abstract and linear as well.Also I study on my own.There is no one to help me out.Will Spivak serve my purpose.Waiting for your valuable reply@John

Comment: You can always post a question here and say "Is this an adequate answer to problem 1.6 in Spivak's Calculus? The problem states ..., and my solution is this: ..." For linear algebra, lots of folks like Strang's book. I personally learned from O'Nan's book, which goes somewhat deeper, and from Hoffman and Kunze, which I cannot recommend -- it's a fine book only for those who already know the subject. Abstract algebra? I like Herstein, because it was the text I used; others love Fraleigh, and I'm sure there are many other fine books. Find one that suits YOU.

Answer (score -1):

suppose {T} is a collection of bounded operators on a Hilbert space H, with  IT<1   for all k. Suppose also that.

Let SN - Σ Ν T k =-Ν

Show that SNf)     converges as N00 , for every Є Н . If  Tf denotes the limit, prove that  |T||< 1 . [Hint: Consider first the case when only finitely many of the  TK are non-zero, and note that the ranges of the TK are mutually orthogonal.]